# Block admin submenu not showing

Tags: admin, magento-1, blocks

[image]

This is a screenshot of my `Magento Admin Panel` in my image is a block not showing. Is there any way to solve this issue.

**Magento 1.9.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

use any patches urgent solution is create tables permission_block and permission_variable see in any magento verison for fields